# Python: Search for string on a text file and display matching rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, search

I have this program right now where it allows users to choose from a category(pulling from the file). Then it will print the University or people from that text file.

What I want to do next on my code is for users to search for a specific string from that file and it will display both the University and People that have that matching string. It can be the whole word or part of the string from that file.

I need help on searching for a given string or part of a string and display matching categories (University and People).

Example:

**search:** ohn

**output:**

University: UCLA Name: J**ohn** Kelly

University: U of Memphis Name: Taylor J**ohn**son

**Here is my current text file:**

```
"UniversityName","ContactName"
"UCLA","John Kelly"
"UofFlorida","Mary Elizabeth"
"U of Memphis","Taylor Johnson"
"Harvard","Robert Fax"
```

This is what I've done so far with my code:

```
def load_data(file_name):
    university_data=[]
    with open(file_name,'r') as rd_file:
        for line in rd_file.readlines():
            line=line.strip().split(',')
            T = line[0],line[1]
            university_data.append(T)
    return university_data

def main():
    filename='List.txt'
    university_data = load_data(filename)
    print('[1] University\n[2] Contact Name\n[3] Exit\n[4] Search')
    while True:

        choice=input('Enter choice 1/2/3? ')
        if choice=='1':
            for university in university_data:
                print(university[0])
        elif choice=='2':
            for university in university_data:
                print(university[1])
        elif choice =='3':
            print('Thank You')
            break
        elif choice =='4':
            print("Search Section Here")
        else:
            print('Invalid selection')

main()
```

Comment: Reinventing `grep`? What's your question?

Comment: I need help is to search for a given string or part of a string and display matching records with fields labeled.

Comment: @smokingpenguin If any of the answers solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Given your data:

```
university_data = [["UniversityName","ContactName"],
["UCLA","John Kelly"],
["UofFlorida","Mary Elizabeth"],
["U of Memphis","Taylor Johnson"],
["Harvard","Robert Fax"]]
```

Use `str.join`:

```
def search(key, data):
    for l in data:
        if key in ''.join(l):
            print('University: %s Name: %s' % (l[0], l[1]))
search('ohn', university_data)
# University: UCLA Name: John Kelly
# University: U of Memphis Name: Taylor Johnson
```

Comment: `univ` is `university_data` in your code. I assume they should be in similar format. Editted

Comment: That makes total sense now. Thank you!

Comment: @smokingpenguin Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the previous answer by [@Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7093741/chris), in case you want to ignore the upper or lowercase of the search word, you can add `lower()` in the `search` function.

```
def search(key, mydata):
    for l in mydata:
        if key in (''.join(l)).lower():
            print('University: %s Name: %s' % (l[0], l[1]))
```